# Cannot use document.write in an XSLT stylesheet (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, xslt, document.write

I've created an XSL stylesheet that has some embedded JavaScript. It calls functions that in turn call document.write() to print the results of these functions to the page.

```
<xsl:foreach...>
<div class="directionBlock">
<script type="text/javascript">writeDirection('<xsl:value-of select="Direction"/>');</script>
</div>
</xsl:foreach...>
```

Unfortunately, in firefox, document.write() is not supported. What to do?

Comment: - Language attribute on script tag should identify a scripting language, not a MIME type. Also, it's misspelled in the code above.
 - document.write is supported in Firefox
 - Clues to your answer are in the error console.
 - there's no document.write in your example code.

Comment: It's very unlikely that XSL stylesheet calls document.write. More likely, it generates an HTML script element which, when activated, calls document.write. The difference is rather important.

Comment: 1. Thanks for that. Will correct. I meant to type script type="text/javascript"/>

2. Correct. Yes. I have a <script> tag that calls a javascript method that in turn makes a call to document.write()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I implemented a solution is to call a function and pass the row number:

```
<xsl:foreach...>
  ...
  <div class="directionBlock">
    <script>myJsFunction('<xsl:value-of select="Direction"/>', <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>);</script>
  </div>
  ...
</xsl:foreach...>
```

This in turn used JQuery to access the element in question, using nth-child(position) to get the row, find a selector and use .html() to insert code into that element.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need both XSLT and Javascript to output HTML? If your aim is to output something in the `div` containing the `script` element then consider to do it with XSLT alone. If you really need to use Javascript to create contents then consider to use methods like `createElement` and `appendChild` instead of `document.write`.
That is as far as a general answer can help, if you need specific help then we need to see details of your code like that `writeDirection` function and the argument you pass to it.

To give you some outline of sample code, if you writeDirection function needs to add content to the div then put an id on the div e.g. `<div id="db1" class="directionBlock">...</div>`, then pass it to the writeDirection function e.g. `<script type="text/javascript">writeDirection('<xsl:value-of select="Direction"/>', document.getElementById('db1'));</script>`, then in that function simply do

```
function writeDirection(dir, elementToWriteTo) {
  // instead of document.write(stuff) use
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = stuff;
  elementToWriteTo.appendChild(span);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. That is exactly what I ended up doing. The reason for needing to call JavaScript is because the client wants complicated formatting of the output data.